# How to fill up the gaps between the blood vessels

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

I have to fill up the gaps between the blood vessels. I have tried dilation with disk and ball type structureing element, but it does not help it only dilates the vessels and gaps still appear. Below attached figure is the segmentation result and corresponding ground truth. [image]

Kindly help me to bridge up the gaps.

Comment: Closing with a disk element might help bridge the smaller gaps — it will connect the vessels across the small gaps without dilating the vessels. However, to bridge the larger gaps you will probably need something more sophisticated like a directional filter and/or a vessel tracing algorithm.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? First image looks pretty good. Do you want to eliminate the thinner vessels? Sometimes this trick helps: dilate your BW image X times (or increase the size of the dilation) and then erode the same times (this may join parts that you don't want to, though). Another "tricky" option is to subtract the skeleton from the original image (so you directly eliminate the thinner vessels) and then fill the gaps (holes) and remove the smaller objects

Comment: @Carlos Borau The first image is ground truth. And second image is my segmentation result. I have to achieve segmentation that is somewhat close to ground truth . I have to fill up the gaps in the second image to make it look close to the first one.

Comment: Did you try dilating several times and then erasing? In any case, you won't get the thinner longer vessels of the ground truth since your initial segmentation removed them. I'd suggest you posting your original image and the method used to segment it. Probably it is easier to fix the segmentation process than to improve the segmentation result afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [imagename, imagepath] = uigetfile({'*.png; *.tif;*.jpg;*.png'},'Select file');
address = fullfile( imagepath,imagename);
a = imread(address);
% figure, imshow(a);
image = imresize(a,  [512 512]);          %Resizing image
tic;
gchanel=image(:,:,2);                         %Green Chanel Extraction
% figure,imshow(gchanel);        
Igchanel = imcomplement(gchanel);             %Inversion
% figure,imshow(Igchanel);
conenhance = adapthisteq(Igchanel);           %Contrast Enhancement
% figure,imshow(conenhance);
g = imgaussfilt(conenhance,2);                %Gaussian filtering
% figure,imshow(g);
se = strel('ball',8,8) ;                     
tophat = imtophat( conenhance,se);             %Tophat transform
% figure,imshow(tophat)
med = medfilt2(tophat);                        %Median filtering
background = imopen(med,strel('disk',15));      
I2 = med - background;                         % Background Removal
% figure,imshow(med);
I3 = imadjust(I2);                             %Intensity Adjustment
level = graythresh(I3);                        % Gray Threshold
bw = im2bw(I3,level);                          % Binarization                                
% figure,imshow(I2);
figure,imshow(bw);
```

@ Carlos Borau above is the code that I tried on the sample image given below.
[image]